# sh: all commands "not found"

Tags: 14.04, bash, paths, sh

I was updating my PATH variable in `.bash_profiles` and `/etc/environment` and I rebooted the system (Ubuntu 14.04).

After login, I got these errors:

```
-sh: 1: id: not found
-sh: 12: [: Illegal number:
```

And I cannot run almost any command. I get `not found` for `ls`, `dir`, `rm`, `mv`, `vi`, and others, so I cannot revert what I did. Any ideas?

Comment: Do commands work if you use their full path e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo nano /etc/environment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your command with the full path, like

```
/bin/ls
/bin/dir
/bin/rm
/bin/mv
/usr/bin/vi
```

Answer (score 2):

To restore your PATH to a sane default, do

```
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
```

This is a problem with your PATH: `-sh: 1: id: not found`

This is a problem with your code: `-sh: 12: [: Illegal number:`

Share your profile for extra help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to do this but to fix it just copy your command scripts from /bin to your new path. REMEMBER these commands may work from their default directory and if you move them they might not find something and have a paddy, so be careful!

Hope this helps